# What would be the right equation to use?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, velocity

I am working on and needed assistance with the [Moving Man Simulation](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/cheerpj/moving-man/latest/moving-man.html?simulation=moving-man). If I wanted to illustrate The Man at an initial starting point/position of $+1$, with a Velocity of $-2$, what equation could I write that may reflect this?  I tried utilizing $()=_0+$ but it did not work. I was confused if I should just use $_0+$ because there is no acceleration.

I really enjoy learning physics (wish I knew how great it was from a younger age) and I am trying but I am no expert (obviously). I am humbly asking for assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x(t) = x_0 + vt$ is the equation of motion for an objecting with initial position $x(0)=x_0$ and constant velocity $v$. In your case $x_0=1$ and $v=-2$, so the equation of motion is $x(t) = 1-2t$. Why do you say it "did not work" ?

Comment: First, thank you.  Maybe I'm overthinking or my inexperience is screaming out but when  I place a number for time (for example 2.1 seconds) the x(t) will be -3.2. WIll that be in meters?

Comment: @יהודה Yes, in metres. The man starts out at a position of $1$ metre to the right of the $0$ point, and travels $2$ metres to the *left* every second, so at $t=2.1$ seconds his position is $3.2$ metres to the left of the zero point, so $x(2.1)=-3.2$.